# Difference between linenumbers of cat file | nl and wc -l file

Tags: unix, ksh

i have a file with e.g. 9818 lines. When i use wc -l file, i see 9818 lines. When i vi the file, i see 9818 lines. When i :set numbers, i see 9818 lines. But when i cat file | nl, i see the final line number is 9750 (e.g.). Basically i'm asking why line numbers from cat file | nl and wc -l file do not match.

Comment: Note that `nl` takes a file as an argument. You don't need to use `cat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**wc -l**: count all lines

**nl**: count all (nonempty) lines

try

**nl -ba**: count all lines

Answer (score 1):

`nl(1)` says the default is for header and footer lines to *not* be numbered (`-hn -fn`), and those are specified by repeating `\;` on various lines. Perhaps your input file includes some of these?

I suggest reading the output of `nl` line by line against `cat -n` output and see where things diverge. Or use `diff -u` if you want to take the fun out of reading 9818 lines. :)

Answer (score 1):

nl does not number blank lines, so this is almost certainly the reason.  If you can point us to the file, we can confirm that, but I suspect this is the case.